# Moodle action menu and edit popup don't show with activity plugin

Tags: javascript, moodle

I created a moodle action plugin to embed videos and everything works fine. Expect the Action menu and other popups.
So normally it should be shown like this

[image]

But when I enabled my plugin on the click nothing happens.

[image]

And it is not working until I uninstall the plugin completly. Uninstalling is not enough I also have to remove it from the file system.

I don't have any clue whats the problem because my plugin have nothing to do with this action menu or edit popup in a course. It's just adding an activity and show a video.

Any idea why this problem occurs in moodle and what is maybe wrong with my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a javascript error, which is stopping all the rest of the javascript on the page from running.

I suggest you open up your browser's debugging tools and look to see if there are any errors appearing - then investigate to see what needs doing to fix them.

Comment: I already try this but there is no Javascript error. And also the Administration and other JavaScript Drowdowns on the left are working properly. There was already an similar problem in moodle 2.6 ... https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-43410